# Add reactid in HTML String

Tags: reactjs, react-native, server-side-rendering, react-server

I am parsing html string into react component on server side, but it is just giving me simple html without attaching any react id, causes I cannot perform event handling and binding.
Can anyone help me how could I add react-id in my html string?

[image: console image]

Comment: can you show some code ?

Comment: @MayankShukla, If you will look, I am sending html as string where server side I render it, but received as no react-id attached. while parent div has attached react-id.

Comment: Have your tried renderToStaticMarkup  instead of  renderToString?